# How can I find out which user earned badge X the most often?

Tags: support, badges, users

Each badge has a list of when and to whom it has been awarded, e.g. [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer). Since some badges can be awarded multiple times, is there a way to get a list of users who earned a specific badge most often?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no dedicated page for this, but this information can be retrieved relatively easily from the Stack Exchange Data Explorer. [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1172809/users-by-number-of-a-specific-badge?BadgeName=Guru) shows Jon Skeet is the ultimate Stack Overflow [Guru](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/18/guru) (not that that needed any further confirmation...).

[image]